# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic) when cloning Git repo

Tags: linux, ssh, git, ubuntu-12.04

I was cloning a Git repository and I had copied my id_rsa key from another PC to my **/home/me/.ssh/** on Ubuntu 12.04, however this error shows up:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Don't copy the key file directly, use `ssh-copy-id` instead.

Comment: after that? should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't just copy the key around. Create a new key for the machine you are using in the same way as you created the one you are copying. According to [this](https://github.com/saga-project/BigJob/wiki/Configuration-of-SSH-for-Password-less-Authentication) page, you should do:

1. Create the key

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t dsa
   ```
2. Copy the content of id_dsa.pub file and append it to the **target machine's** `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If authorized_keys file is not accessible, then just create `.ssh/authorized_keys2` file and paste the key.

   ```
   cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
3. Copy the key to the target machine

   ```
   ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add < /dev/null && bash'
   ```

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` does the same thing: once the key is in place, you can just `ssh-copy-id username@host`.

Comment: what about may old ssh key? will I still be use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the contents of `id_rsa.pub` in the file `/home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

`id_rsa` is your private key and should be protected carefully.

Comment: I don't see any authorized_keys under my .ssh folder. should I make it?

Comment: Yes, that file has to exist and contain your trusted public key(s).

Comment: how would I do/create that? I don't know the format

Comment: Just copy `id_rsa.pub` from the client machine to the server, and rename it as `/home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I have no access to the server.I just did a fresh install of ubuntu. and copied the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from my windows 7 machine to ubuntu.

Comment: Ah! I've just realised what you're trying to do.  OK, so it looks like you've done the right thing, and your problem might be permissions.  Make sure that the keys, and the `.ssh` directory, are only readable by you.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: `cd /home/me; chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: I just typed the code you have given should I expect any outputs? I tried running git again however the error still exists